# SwiftUI iOS - switch between views but choose which should be shown first

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and having experience with couple other languages, including JAVA, I must say that Swift is by far the weirdest..

I followed a tutorial on how to create a "switch" view in which I can switch between other views without using NavigationLink

I have those files

Helpfer.swift:

```
import Foundation

enum Page {
    case login
    case register
}
```

ViewRouter.swift

```
import SwiftUI

    class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
            
        @Published var currentPage: Page = Page.login
        
    }
```

As you can see the page login is pre set

In the ContentView I have a NavigationLink leading to the "switch" view:

```
NavigationLink(destination: SwitchView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), showThisPage: .register).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), label: {
    Text("go to switch view")
})
```

as you can see I want `register` to be set instead of `login` this time

I tried all kind of stuff in the SwitchView, this was the last:

import SwiftUI

```
struct SwitchView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    var showThisPage: Page
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch viewRouter.currentPage {
        case .login:
            Login(viewRouter: viewRouter)
        case .register:
            CreateAccount(viewRouter: viewRouter)
        }
    }
}

struct SwitchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwitchView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), showThisPage: Page)
    }
}
```

and get:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Page.Type' to expected argument type 'Page'
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like nobody understands what I want, so again and more clearly:

**I need to pass** `showThisPage: .register` ***through NavigationLink in*** `ContentView` **to** `SwitchView` **and in** `SwitchView` **I need to catch this value and use it to be recognized in**

```
case .register:
    CreateAccount(viewRouter: viewRouter)
}
```

How?

Comment: Change `switch viewRouter.currentPage` to `switch showThisPage`

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a value to `showThisPage` in your preview, so replace this:

```
SwitchView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), showThisPage: Page)
```

with:

```
SwitchView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), showThisPage: Page.login) //or Page.register
```

Besides, you're not using `showThisPage` in your code.

Comment: I need to declare which view I want to see inside ContentView instead of SwitchView by passing this information from ContentView to SwitchView

Comment: then replace viewRouter.currentPage with  viewRouter.currentPage

Comment: Replacing viewRouter.currentPage with viewRouter.currentPage ??

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! I mean with showThisPage

Comment: Ok but what do I write as second parameter in SwitchView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), showThisPage: Page()) ?? In any sane language you just declare the type that needs to be passed here, but what the hell does swift want ??

Comment: The type is declared it wants a value because this is a preview. Just add what you want to preview see my answer

Comment: @EduardUnruh _”… but what the hell does swift want”_, like most other languages it wants a value as has been shown in the answer.

Comment: Mind your language please. You pass it like you are doing right now in your code but that is not what the question is about since it’s in the preview you get an error and it was the preview my comment was about.

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Page is the type of the parameter. You have to give the value, not the Type.
You should use it like this:

> struct SwitchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
> static var previews: some View {
> SwitchView(viewRouter: ViewRouter(), showThisPage: .register)
> } }

Comment: I need to declare which view I want to see inside ContentView instead of SwitchView by passing this information from ContentView to SwitchView

Comment: Please check my edit